# Do we need to create separate IIS web apps for each provider hosted app in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on Sharepoint provider hosted app. So as per different, we can to host our app on IIS server and for that we need to create a website on IIS server. My question is that do we need to create a separate website each time we create a provider hosted app. I need to create around 50 provider hosted apps, so does that mean there will 50 IIS websites corresponding to those?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create different websites. You have 2 options to do this.

1) Create a single Website in IIS and add each Provider Hosted apps as a separate applications in that website.

2) Create a single Solution to handle all 50 Provider Hosted apps. That is single web project to support all the 50 apps. You can add any number of services in a web project. So, Create a individual services for 50 apps in a single web project. Host it in a single website. Just the service name should be vary for all 50 apps. Be planned to do this before you starts.

Thanks.